# "truffle init" creates files with read only permissions

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm wondering if this was intentional that truffle creates all its folders and files as read-only. Every time I use truffle to generate files, I have to manually change the permissions with chmod so that I can write to them.

Is this an issue with how I installed truffle globally and with sudo?

Example of a file's permissions that I just created with `truffle create contract`

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  122 Apr 10 01:28 BasicContract.sol
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  419 Apr  9 23:13 Migrations.sol
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution: Run the truffle command under regular user, not using sudo.**

---

```
truffle create contract MyContract
```

creates the file with 644 permissions owned by the regular user

```
-rw-r--r--   1 petrhejda  staff  119 Apr 10 11:42 MyContract.sol
```

---

But

```
sudo truffle create contract MyContract2
```

creates the file with 644 permissions, but owned by root (so that your regular user doesn't have write permissions)

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root       staff  120 Apr 10 11:42 MyContract2.sol
```

Comment: Makes sense. I had to change the permissions of ".config/truffle/config.json" before I could run it as a regular user.